# How to remove HTML Tags in Python3

Tags: python, html, regex, parsing, urllib

I am writing a simple script to print out my IP Address in terminal. I am having trouble removing the HTML tags from the print statement.

I have tried using the .strip() function from the urllib library. I do not understand regex enough to input into this code.

```
import re
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import json


data = urllib.request.urlopen('http://checkip.dyndns.org')
for line in data:
    print(line.decode().strip())
```

I expect the output to solely be my IP (xxx.xx.xx.xxx) but instead am getting the following

"< html>< head>< title>Current IP Check< /title>< /head>< body>Current IP Address: XXX.XX.XX.XXX< /body>< /html>"

Comment: is there only one line in `data`?

Comment: print(line.decode().strip().replace('Current IP CheckCurrent IP Address: ',''))

Comment: @LeeGarcon - There is only one line in data I believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use regex, instead of stripping tags you can just match the part you are interested in using parentheses, here's an example:

```
import re
import urllib.request


data = urllib.request.urlopen('http://checkip.dyndns.org').read().decode()
print(re.search(r'Current IP Address: ([\d\.]+)', data).group(1))
```

You can find more info and examples at https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects

For removing HTML tags in general you can use something like this using re:

```
print(re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', '<html>foo</html>'))
```

Or even easier using BeatufilSoup instead of re:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
print(BeautifulSoup('<html>foo</html>').get_text())
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thank you! The regex solution worked well.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is not a difficult string manipulation problem, but there's a much cleaner way to do it using a different service. One is [ipify.org](https://www.ipify.org/).

```
import json
from urllib import request

with request.urlopen('https://api.ipify.org?format=json') as response:
    print(json.loads(response.read())['ip'])
```

Comment: That did seem to work using JSON. Thanks! And yes, indeed it's not difficult, I am quite the novice.

Comment: You're welcome! My point was less about your skill than the fact that backing all the way up and asking whether there are good program-friendly options available is often a good way to start that's easily overlooked.